# Error 404, cannot find the requested url while trying to call api endpoint

Tags: angular

I am getting a 404 not found error while trying to create a new customer in my angular 10 application. I have tested the API method from Postman and it works perfectly fine. It fails when called from the angular client. I am not sure what is wrong

In postman, I call url http://localhost:7071/api/add-customer and the data is set in the body

The error i see in the console is as follows

```
Request URL: http://localhost:7071/api/add-customer,%20[object%20Object]

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:7071
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 14:42:57 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:7071
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/customers
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
{headers: {normalizedNames: {}, lazyUpdate: null}}
headers: {normalizedNames: {}, lazyUpdate: null}
```

Component

```
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log('OnSubmit fired');
    this.customerDetailsService.addCustomer(this.customer).subscribe(data => data );
    console.log(this.customer);
   }
```

Service

```
export class CustomerService extends BaseService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient, private customerEndpoint: CustomerEndpointService) {
    super(http);
  }

  getCustomerDetails = (): Observable<ICustomer[]> => this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(this.customerEndpoint.getCustomerDetails(),
    this.getRequestHeaders())

  addCustomer = (customer): Observable<ICustomer> => this.http.post<ICustomer>(this.customerEndpoint.addCustomer(customer),
    this.getRequestHeaders())

  updateCustomer = (customer): Observable<ICustomer> => this.http.put<ICustomer>(this.customerEndpoint.updateCustomer(customer),
    this.getRequestHeaders())

  deleteCustomer = (id): any => this.http.delete(this.customerEndpoint.deleteCustomer(id), this.getRequestHeaders());
}
```

Base Service

```
export class BaseService {

  baseUrl: string = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

  protected getRequestHeaders(): {headers: HttpHeaders | {[header: string ]: string | string[]; }} {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           Accept: `application/json, text/plain, */*`,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'
      });
      return {headers};
  }
}
```

CustomerEndpointService

```
export class CustomerEndpointService extends BaseService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

  getCustomerDetails = (): string =>  `${this.baseUrl}/api/customers-details`;

  addCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/add-customer, ${customer}`;

  updateCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/update-customer, ${customer}`;

  deleteCustomer = (id): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/delete-customer/${id}`;
}
```

Comment: "%20[object%20Object]" - your body params are not okay that's why you are getting error. Please check POST params

Comment: Which data format your api is expecting? Object or Array ?

Comment: its expecting Object

Comment: @Abu Sufian  I have update the post

Comment: could you please recheck that customer is object that you are trying to post as body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method to get the addCustomer (and updateCustomer most likely) urls are wrong.  You are tying to append a comma and the string representation of your customer object to the end of the URL.

Your addCustomer url doesn't need to know anything about the customer, and your post method is not including the custom in the body

Updated CustomerEndpointService

```
  addCustomer = (): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/add-customer`;

// Not sure what the primary key field is on customer, assuming its customer.id
  updateCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/update-customer/ ${customer.id}`;
```

Updated CustomerService

```js
addCustomer = (customer): Observable<ICustomer> => this.http.post<ICustomer>(this.customerEndpoint.addCustomer(), customer,
    this.getRequestHeaders())

  updateCustomer = (customer): Observable<ICustomer> => this.http.put<ICustomer>(this.customerEndpoint.updateCustomer(customer), customer,
    this.getRequestHeaders())
```

Comment: I am still getting 404 error. This time the url is Request URL: http://localhost:7071/api/add-customer,%20undefined

Comment: Your addCustomer code is still trying to add `,${customer}` at the end of the URL

Comment: My code was upto date with your changes but building the code and doing a ctrl + f5 on the browser took the changes into account. Thanks. It works now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these 2 lines are your problem. Post and puts expect 2 arguments, you have 1 separated by a comma.
Change

```
addCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/add-customer, ${customer}`;

updateCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/update-customer, ${customer}`;
```

to

```
addCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/add-customer`, customer;

updateCustomer = (customer): string => `${this.baseUrl}/api/update-customer`, customer;
```

Happy coding!